# get dropdownlist selected value from database

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am having a dropdown list having multiple items, and users saves any selected value. but when i am trying to fetch data from database to dropdown list. the dropdown list is showing initial value instead of database value.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddimportance" Height="32" runat="server">
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="High" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="Medium" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="Low" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
                                     <asp:ListItem Text="NA" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
                                </asp:DropDownList>



using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(st))
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spGetUploadedImage", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PId", Convert.ToInt32(ddproject.SelectedValue.ToString()));
        SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (rd.Read())
        {
            txtuserdomain.Text = rd["P_user_domain"].ToString();
            txtawards.Text = rd["P_awards"].ToString();
            txtcoverage.Text = rd["P_functional_coverage"].ToString();
            txtfeatures.Text = rd["P_feature"].ToString();
            txtimplementation.Text = rd["P_implementation"].ToString();
            //lblimportance.Text = rd["Importance"].ToString();
            //ddimportance.ClearSelection();
            ddimportance.Items.FindByText(rd["Importance"].ToString()).Selected = true;}
```

Comment: Do you want to bind your DropDown from the Database Value?

Comment: Set `AutoPostBack="true"` for the DropDwon maybe that helps you.

Comment: ddimportance.SelectedValue = rd["Importance"].ToString();

Comment: Like @JawadAnwar said use can simply set AutoPostBack="true" which should fix the problem.